# VS 2015: Profiling tools disabled in Performance Wizard

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, dnx, asp.net5

I want to sample the performance of our application, but the various tools (such as CPU Usage and Application Timeline) are not available when trying to start a new profiling session with the Performance Wizard:

[image: Profiling Tools]

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Professional.  The application is using ASP.NET 5 RC1 and is running from Kestrel (not IIS).

Why could this be happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a workaround, you can use the "Diagnostic Tools" panel when debugging, it has a CPU profiler built in.